# How does heat math works? Are heat exchangers additive or multiplicative or something else?

Tags: battletech, battletech-heavy-metal

I got my hands on a couple of Exchangers++ in the black market, each should reduce heat from my weapons by 20%, so 40% total.

However, in a field, my mech is overheating much more than I have expected.

[image]

I have done [some reading](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/heat-exchanger-math.1143438/) around and some claim that exchangers are multiplicative, but the math does not work out for them either.

**What is the math behind Battletech heat and heat exchangers?**

Comment: What values pop up when you hover over Heat Efficiency ? Maybe there's an order that sinks / exchangers are applied or something.

Answer (score 1):

Heat exchangers are multiplicative. If you have 2 ++exchangers (20% reduced heat each), your total heat output will be 0.8^2 = 64% of the original. Note that:

- How BT rounds numbers may be wonky.
- The heat bar isn't a very good indication of your mech's true efficiency. However, if you hover your mouse over it, the tooltip figures should be accurate.